# Swift filter object array wit another object array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

i struggle my had now sine several days with a way to do conditional filter of an object array with another object array.

lack on capabilities to properly abstract here... maybe you ahve some ideas.

I have a given Object Array A but more complex

```
var ArrA = [{
 number: 1,
 name: "A"
}, {
 number: 2,
 name: "C"
}]
```

And i want to filer for all results matiching id of Object Array B

```
var ArrB = [{
 id: 1,
 categorie: "wine"
}, {
 id: 3,
 categorie: "beer"
}, {
 id: 10,
 categorie: "juice"
}]
```

And in the best case moving this directly also together with an if condition.... but i was not able to handle it ... here is where i am now ... which is not working....

```
let newArray = ArrA.filter{$0.number == ArrB.... }.
if (newArray.count != 0){
    // Do something
}
```

is there a lean way to compare one attribute of every object in an array with one attribute of another every object in an array ?

Comment: This is called the "intersection" of two arrays, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break this down: You need all **arrA** objects that matches **arrB** ids, so first thing first you need to `map` your **arrB** to a list of id (because you dont need the other infos)

`let arrBid = Set(arrB.map({ $0.id })) // [1, 3, 10]`

*As commented below, casting it to `Set` will give you better results for huge arrays but is not mandatory though*

Then you just need to filter your first **arrA** by only keeping object that id is contained into **arrBid** :

`let arrAFilter = arrA.filter({ arrBid.contains($0.number) })`

> [(number: 1, name: "A")]

and voila

Comment: Use a `Set` for faster `contains`: `let arrBid = Set(arrB.map { $0.id })`.  `contains` is O(n) for an `Array` and O(1) for a `Set`.

Comment: You don't need the `return` inside the `map` and `filter` closures.

Comment: @vacawama I know, you do not need them if there is only a single line in the closure, I find it clearer though but it may not be the case for everyone

Comment: Hey that is great.. it works like a charm ! Thank you... i really was struggeling how to get a single attribute array from my objects :) ... any chance i can combine the filter with the if statement as well ?

Comment: @Bliv_Dev you could do `let arrAFilter = arrA.filter({ Set(arrB.map({ $0.id })).contains($0.number) })` but I suggest you do NOT. the reason is that the closure you put inside `filter()` will be triggered for each element, therefore it will compute the `map` for each element in arrA, which is not optimal at all